# Как сделать так что бы при запуске программы в python с командой для перехода на сайт она не выполнялась при запуске

Tags: python

Здрасте, я хотел написать программу для быстрого перехода на сайт с гдз, я использую библиотеку webbrowser. Хотел я сделать так чтобы нажимая на кнопку перекидывало на сайт гдз, но программа сначала открывает сайт, а потом при нажатии на кнопку ничего не происходит. Я применял очень много разных способов как это исправить но ничего не нашел. Вот код:

```
from tkinter import *


class algebra:
    def alg(self):
        import webbrowser
        webbrowser.open("https://gdz.ru/class-7/english/afanaseva-11/86/")



alg = algebra()



root = Tk()

Label(root)

lab1 = Label(root, text='Выбирете учебник')
lab1.place(relx=0.01,rely=0.01)

btn1 = Button(root, text='Алгебра', command=alg.alg())
btn1.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.06, anchor=CENTER)



root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

`command=alg.alg())`  убрать лишние скобки `command=alg.alg)`